# How to test a mail server using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, mail-server

I have a Webmail application which is based on a Mdaemon mail server.

Now I'm able to load test the web application using JMeter, but I want to know if it's possible to load test the Mdaemon mail server directly, without testing the web app?

I address the application in Jmeter using the server's IP and the port.but I don't know how to address Mdaemon which is installed on the server, directly in Jmeter.

Comment: JMeter is for testing webservers; it's not the appropriate tool for testing mail servers.

Comment: don't believe skaffman, Jmeter is easily extendable. It even has built-in IMAP sampler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an SMTP Sampler and a Mail Reader Sampler:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler

So what you are looking for is already built in.